# Movil ya no se conecta a android studio offline

Tags: android

Hasta hace dos semanas el movil se conectaba a android studio para ejecutar las app hechas. Pero ahora se conecta y rapidamente se desconecta.

El ADB Interfaces no lo reconoce. He intentaado un monton de cosas pero sigue sin reconocerlo (mas bien lo reconoce pero cuando voy a jececuralo tanto por  Run como por Debug app se descoencta.

¿Que puede estar pasando y como solucionarlo?

Comment: Puede ser problemas del cable, usb 3.0, virus, te puede servir https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12491/adb-constantly-disconnects-shows-device-offline. Puede que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida en los otros sitios de SO.

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado, puede ser tu cable, el driver, un antivirus, incluso tu propio dispositivo físico, has intentado con otro?

Comment: He cambiado de cable, de telefono y sigue igual. El antivirus es el mismo y me dice que no hay ningun virus.

Comment: He probado con todo y en android studio en la opcion de Troublesshoot device connetions issues dice al conectar por usb el movil : Device was detected by ADB but not Android Studio. ¿Puede ser algo de alguna actualizacion de android studio?